# How can I get the spindle driver current internally?

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, machining, cnc

I am working on monitoring research. During it I found a lot of papers use Hall effect sensors to get spindle current. However some of them are accessed internally to spindle driver current. I will be thankful if any cnc professional can guide me how to access internally to spindle current and which types of cnc have this ability?

Comment: Most modern industrial CNC controllers have spindle load monitors. That might be a starting point for you

Comment: I updated your question. Please re-read to make sure changes have not affected  your original intent.